# How to make left elements unaffected when using display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

```css
.location-text {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  align-items: center;
  color: #13233A;
}

.list-contact {
  display: flex;
}

.icon-address {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #EAA9A9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bootCols">
  <div class="title location">
    <i class="bx bx-location-plus localst"></i>
    <span class="location-text">Trụ sở (TP. Vinh)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-contact">
    <div class="icon-address">
      <img src="./image/home/address.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="content-address">
      <span>Do Something Do Something Do Something Do Something Do Something Do        Something Do Something</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a frame like the following and I want to display flex so that they are on one row:

[image]

And I wanted the icon and content to be on the same line so I used display flex and it affected the width of the right icon. Here is my HTML and CSS code:

And this is the result I got:

[image]

So is there a way to make the element containing my icon unaffected? Hope to get a solution from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, every flex child has `flex-shrink: 1` assigned, which cause them to shrink to its minimum content width when there are no enough space.

To counter that, you just need to manually assign it to `0` so it will keep its assigned size which is `22px`.

See more about [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink).

```css
.icon-address {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```css
.location-text {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  align-items: center;
  color: #13233A;
}

.list-contact {
  display: flex;
}

.icon-address {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #EAA9A9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bootCols">
  <div class="title location">
    <i class="bx bx-location-plus localst"></i>
    <span class="location-text">Trụ sở (TP. Vinh)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="list-contact">
    <div class="icon-address">
      <img src="./image/home/address.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="content-address">
      <span>Do Something Do Something Do Something Do Something Do Something Do        Something Do Something</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put the elements correctly, so that the layout is as expected

```css
.location-text{
font-family: 'Inter';
display: inline-block;
word-break: break-word;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 26px;
align-items: center;
color: #13233A;
}
.list-contact{
 display: flex;
}
.icon-address{
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #EAA9A9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-address{
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bootCols">
  <div class="title location">
    <i class="bx bx-location-plus localst"></i>
    <span class="location-text">Trụ sở (TP. Vinh)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-address">
        <img src="./image/home/address.png" alt="">
    </div>
  <div class="list-contact">
    <div class="content-address">
     <span>Do Something Do Something Do Something Do Something Do Something Do        Something Do Something</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```